# Associate and Search on a document metadata using Google Drive APIs

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way I can have my own metadata associated to a document that I am uploading to Google Drive? If yes, how do I mention that metadata in the API?

Also, can I perform a search using the metadata using the APIs. Say if there are 3 documents with the metadata tag as 'cooking' ... can I use the search API where I send the tag 'cooking' as a search query and I get a list of all the docs associated with that metadata.

Regards, Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see custom file properties. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/properties

To search for custom file properties, add this to your search parameters:

properties has { key = 'foo' and value = 'bar' and visibility = 'private'}

Note that all 3 parts are required.

Comment: I tried a few months to search by file properties and didn't work. I see that now the docs say its searchable.

Comment: the above link explains how to add the custom file properties .. but I am still not able to figure out how to perform a search based on these custom file properties ... basically i need to provide a property value and the search api should return me a list of files which have the corresponding value in the custom file properties

Comment: I edited with the query syntax.  Sorry, it looks like this wasn't well documented.